# I am gathering all the Azure subnets for Central US and trying to filter out the smaller subnets that are part of the larger... Very slow

Tags: performance, powershell, ip-address

The goal of this code is to *remove subnets from the list that are redundant* (included in the larger ones)
It is **VERY** slow.  Wondering how it can be sped up.

At present, I’m not looking to optimize the “CheckSubnet()” function, which isn’t my code... It MAY be slow (or not) but I’m hoping that a critical analysis of the code that I HAVE presented can expose something obvious that I might have missed.

CheckSubnet Function taken from here: http://www.gi-architects.co.uk/2016/02/powershell-check-if-ip-or-subnet-matchesfits/

The function takes two CIDR notated subnets and returns an object that has two parts:

1. `bool` `Condition` which is `TRUE` if one of the subnets contains the other
2. `string` SomeotherMemeberThatIDontCareAbout

My code is as follows:

```
if ((Get-Module az.network) -eq $null)
{
    Import-Module az.network -Prefix AN
}
$Ranges = (Get-ANAzNetworkServiceTag -Location CentralUS).Values.Properties.AddressPrefixes | Sort-Object -Unique
#
#I think you need to be logged into your Azure Subscription for this to gather the results
#$Ranges returns over 8100 unique subnets
#
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$15 = $Ranges | ?{$_ -like "*/15"}
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$16 = $Ranges | ?{$_ -like "*/16"}
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$17 = $Ranges | ?{$_ -like "*/17"}
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$18 = $Ranges | ?{$_ -like "*/18"}
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$19 = $Ranges | ?{$_ -like "*/19"}
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$20 = $Ranges | ?{$_ -like "*/20"}
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$21 = $Ranges | ?{$_ -like "*/21"}
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$22 = $Ranges | ?{$_ -like "*/22"}
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$23 = $Ranges | ?{$_ -like "*/23"}
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$24 = $Ranges | ?{$_ -like "*/24"}
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$25 = $Ranges | ?{$_ -like "*/25"}
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$26 = $Ranges | ?{$_ -like "*/26"}
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$27 = $Ranges | ?{$_ -like "*/27"}
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$28 = $Ranges | ?{$_ -like "*/28"}
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$29 = $Ranges | ?{$_ -like "*/29"}
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$30 = $Ranges | ?{$_ -like "*/30"}
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$31 = $Ranges | ?{$_ -like "*/31"}
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$32 = $Ranges | ?{$_ -like "*/32"}

[System.Collections.ArrayList]$arrays= $15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,$21,$22,$23,$24,$25,$26,$27,$28,$29,$30,$31,$32

for ($j =0;$j -le $arrays.Count-1;$j++)
{

    [System.Collections.ArrayList]$target = $arrays[$j+1]    
    $target.Count
    $counter =1

    [System.Collections.ArrayList]$ArraySubset=$arrays
    [System.Collections.ArrayList]$arraySubset.RemoveRange($j+1,$arrays.Count-($j+1))
    foreach ($Big in $arraySubset)
    {
        $iteration=0
        $thecount=$target.Count
        Write-host "Array number: $counter  Remaining: $thecount"

        foreach ($largecidr in $Big)
        {
            for($i=$target.count-1;$i -ge 0;$i--)
            {
                $iteration++
                $checkval=CheckSubnet $largecidr $target[$i]
                if ($checkval.Condition -eq $true)
                {
                    Write-Host "Removing $($target[$i])"
                    $target[$i]
                    $target.RemoveAt($i)
                }
                if ($iteration % 100 -eq 0)
                {
                    Write-Host "Iteration $iteration"
                }
            }
        }
        $counter++
    }
    [System.Collections.ArrayList]$arrays= $15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,$21,$22,$23,$24,$25,$26,$27,$28,$29,$30,$31,$32
}
$target.Count
```

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview@SE. Please edit into your question why to assume `CheckSubnet()`, called in the innermost loop, doesn't significantly contribute to the lamented performance. Or present its code, too. Have a look at [How do I ask a Good Question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @greybeard thanks for fixing up some formatting.  I don’t want to analyze CheckSubnet() (yet) as it isn’t my code - as referenced by my link to its location on the ‘Net.  Hoping that there just might be a better approach to working through the subsets to do the comparison.

Comment: The posted code doesn't have any obvious problems AFAICT. There's one thing missing though: measurements. Any performance analysis and improvement should start with measurements, otherwise it'd be a random guesswork. Look for examples of measuring execution time in powershell code, it's a rather tedious process when you have to isolate timing of sections inside loops.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks for the feedback! Will have a look.  The woke thing took over 72 hours to complete, when I DID let it finally run to completion.

Comment: You can show the currently accumulated measurements every 10 seconds, for example.